# DoubleClick for Publishers - support multiple screen sizes

Tags: web, banner

I'm showing banner at left in my web page.
According to screen size 160x600 or 300x600 have to be used.

I can determine screen size and set proper code, but I think this isn't correct way.

Does somebody know how to leave to DoubleClick to decide which one ad fits better in page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately DoubleClick documentation is from ancient times :)
Solution: Do not put baner size in web page. Set it dynamicaly in javascript code provided from Doubleclick.